# Published property change does not update the interface

Tags: swiftui

I have this class:

```
class MyObject:ObservableObject, Hashable {
  static func == (lhs: PageView, rhs: PageView) -> Bool {
    lhs.id == rhs.id
  }
  
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
  }
  
  @Published var visible:Bool
  @Published var myObject:MyObject
  
  let id = UUID()
  init(_ myObject:MyObject) {
    self.myObject = myObject
    self.isVisible = false
  }
}
```

and this model

```
class MyModel:ObservableObject {
  @Published var myObjects = [MyObject]()
  ...
}
```

later in the app I have this:

```
  @ObservedObject private var myModel:MyModel
  
  
  init(_ myModel:MyModel) {
    self.myModel = myModel
  }

  ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    ForEach(model.myObjects, id: \.self) { object in
      MyPanel(object)
        .opacity(object.isVisible ? 1 : 0.6)
        .allowsHitTesting(object.isVisible)
    }
  }
```

the objects appear semi transparent initially. I change the `isVisible` property of an object, it continues transparent on the scrollView.

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyModel` will only publish changes if the `myObjects` array property is changed. From `MyModel`'s point of view, it has an array of object references. If you change a property on one of those objects, then nothing has changed, it still has the same array of the same object references.

`MyObject` is an observable object, but nothing is observing it.

You should make `MyPanel` hold the object that you are passing it as an observable object, and have it set its own opacity and hit testing rather than have it done at the scroll view level. This way only the leaf view will re-render rather than the entire scroll view.

Comment: It took me so long to truly understand this. This article helped a lot. https://rhonabwy.com/2021/02/13/nested-observable-objects-in-swiftui/